# How to have a Spring OAuth2 client pass an access token to Vaadin frontend for creating sessions

Tags: spring, spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin14

We use an external OAuth2 server to handle our logins and a Spring Boot + Vaadin application authenticating against it. The access token coming from the OAuth2 flow is stored on the server and we use regular servlet sessions that way.

We want to support a "remember me" functionality so that users don't need to log in after being idle for a while, but the OAuth2 Spring configuration doesn't support it, so we're attempting to roll our own. So far we are storing the OAuth2 access token in a cookie, sending it back to the client, and having the Spring Boot OAuth2 resource server handle the token.

The application uses the default Push configuration (websocket on the server, XHR on the client). What we find is that everything works as expected, but when the Vaadin frontend attempts to create a session, we see that Vaadin repeatedly fails to set up a new session when initialising the websocket, but eventually (5-20 attempts) works. An example failing request:

```
scheme
    wss
filename
    /
v-r
    push
v-uiId
    3
v-pushId
    01dbe313-f709-4ee3-8e7c-07e566f6d384
X-Atmosphere-tracking-id
    0
X-Atmosphere-Framework
    3.1.2-javascript
X-Atmosphere-Transport
    websocket
X-Atmosphere-TrackMessageSize
    true
Content-Type
    application/json; charset=UTF-8
X-atmo-protocol
    true
Response
    55|for(;;);[{"meta":{"async":true,"sessionExpired":true}}]
```

The goal is to have Vaadin correctly create a session on the first request rather than continually reject them and lead to 60s+ "loading" times.

I've looked at Vaadin's (Hilla's) support for stateless authentication, but I don't think it's appropriate as the application is not issuing tokens, just passing them along.

Relevant classes:

```java
@PageTitle(TITLE_ROOT)
@PreserveOnRefresh
@Push(value = PushMode.AUTOMATIC, transport = Transport.WEBSOCKET_XHR)
@Theme(value = "lumo")
@Viewport(VIEWPORT)
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class AppShell implements AppShellConfigurator {}
```

```java
public class CookieBearerTokenResolver implements BearerTokenResolver {

  private @Nullable Cookie getCookie(Cookie @Nullable [] cookies, String name) {
    if (cookies == null) {
      return null;
    }
    for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
      if (cookie.getName().equals(name)) {
        return cookie;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public @Nullable String resolve(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Cookie cookie =
        getCookie(request.getCookies(), JwtCookieAuthenticationSuccessHandler.ACCESS_TOKEN);
    if (cookie == null || !StringUtils.hasLength(cookie.getValue())) {
      return null;
    }
    return cookie.getValue();
  }
}
```

```java
public class JwtCookieAuthenticationSuccessHandler
    extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

  public static final String ACCESS_TOKEN = "access_token";

  private Cookie[] createCookies(
      HttpServletRequest request, OAuth2AuthenticationToken oauth2Authentication) {
    var accessToken = new Cookie(ACCESS_TOKEN, encodeAccess(oauth2Authentication));
    finaliseCookie(request, accessToken);

    return new Cookie[] {accessToken};
  }

  private @Nullable String encodeAccess(OAuth2AuthenticationToken oauth2Authentication) {
    if (oauth2Authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof OidcUser oidcUser) {
      return oidcUser.getIdToken().getTokenValue();
    }
    return null;
  }

  private void finaliseCookie(HttpServletRequest request, Cookie cookie) {
    cookie.setMaxAge(AbstractRememberMeServices.TWO_WEEKS_S);
    cookie.setPath(getCookiePath(request));
    cookie.setSecure(request.isSecure());
    cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
  }

  private String getCookiePath(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String contextPath = request.getContextPath();
    return (contextPath.length() > 0) ? contextPath : "/";
  }

  @Override
  public void onAuthenticationSuccess(
      HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
      throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (authentication instanceof OAuth2AuthenticationToken oauth2Authentication) {
      for (var cookie : createCookies(request, oauth2Authentication)) {
        if (StringUtils.hasLength(cookie.getValue())) {
          response.addCookie(cookie);
        }
      }
    }
    super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
  }
}
```

```java
@Component
public class SecurityConfiguration extends VaadinWebSecurity {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
    http.oauth2ResourceServer()
        .bearerTokenResolver(new CookieBearerTokenResolver())
        .jwt();
    http.oauth2Login()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .successHandler(new JwtCookieAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
        .permitAll();
  }
}
```